# GetHeadPostion vs GetNext for iteration

Tags: c++, mfc

I have noticed you can also transverse a list by doing the following

```
for (POSITION curPos = batchRescheduleReasons.GetHeadPosition(); curPos != NULL;)
{
    m_pRescheduleReasons.push_back(new CSchRescheduleReasons(batchRescheduleReasons.GetNext(curPos)));
}
```

However GetHeadPostion() only returns the head of the list so how does it iterate? is the head incremented within GetHeadPostion()?

Shouldnt we do the following?

```
POSITION pos = MyIntList.GetHeadPosition();

while (pos)
{
  int Number = MyIntList.GetNext(pos);
  // do something with the number
}
```

Comment: Your two code snippets are exactly equivalent. The initialization clause of a `for` statement only runs once.

Comment: If `getNext` changes `curPos` both are the same. If it doesn't it shouldn't work IMO

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi the loop will run multiple time if batchRescheduleReasons is > 1

Comment: @Shamari, yes, the loop will run multiple times, but the initialization clause `curPos = batchRescheduleReasons.GetHeadPosition()` will only run once. `GetNext()` is responsible for iteration (it takes its `POSITION` argument by reference for that purpose).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ah yes correct